# WebAPI - Return Response from Initialize (override) method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, filter, controller, asp.net-web-api2

I have the same code on each API method:

```
        if (user.AspNetRoles.Where(p => p.Name == Models.Roles.SmartphonePhotographer).Count() == 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)453, new { Message = "User does not have Smartphone Photographer role" });
            //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User does not have Smartphone Photographer role");
        }

        if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)454, new { Message = "User is not confirmed" });
        }
```

and want to return Response directly from override Initialize method. Can I do it?

(Of course, I have moved it to ActionFilter if had not set user variable in Controller)

```
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        int id = controllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        user = controllerContext.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(id);

        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override Initialize method is a void method so you can't return response result, 
You should write on the response but in the Initialize method the response still not completed yet.
[see this link](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf)

You can reroute to your method which return your response like the below

```
 protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var  newControllerContext = controllerContext
            //edit RouteData to refer to your controller/action
        newControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = "YourAction"
        base.Initialize(newControllerContext);
    }
```